# How is non-blocking IO actually works from client's perspective?

Tags: http, nonblocking

So I came across the idea of blocking and non-blocking I/O. But what I understood from the concept and some of the sample implementations is that we implement code on the server side to achieve this nature of the code.

But now my question is, if (for example postman sending HTTP request to the server) the request has to wait for the server to respond, then what's the point of non-blocking I/O? (Please correct me if I am wrong) Or the whole concept is just for the increase of throughput of the server instead of actual async nature w.r.t. to client.

For example, in one of my project what I did was created a post request to create a request in the system for processing which will return the transaction ID, now using this transaction id, I can query the server to know the outcome.

I may sound too naive, but the concept has confused me a lot. I do not understand this concept clearly. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the request has to wait for the server to respond, then what's the point of non-blocking I/O?

There's a confusion. Waiting for a response and (non)blocking i/o are very loosely related. You always have to wait for response. That's why youve made the request to begin with. But the question is: how?

Non-blocking HTTP: "Dear server, here's my request, please process it and send me a response, I'm going to do something else in the meantime, like calculating n-th digit of Pi (I'm a weirdo)".

Blocking HTTP: "Dear server, here's my request, please process it and send me a response, I'm going to patiently wait for it doing nothing".

> Or the whole concept is just for the increase of throughput of the server instead of actual async nature w.r.t. to client.

The whole concept is to be able to do other things while waiting for i/o at the same time. And to do that while minimizing the usage of threads which don't scale well.

Asynchronous systems, i.e. systems without "I'm going to wait idly" part tend to perform better at the cost of complexity.

*Side note:* nonblocking i/o can be used both on the server side and client side. For example almost all JS engines in browsers are built on top of some asynchronous engine. JS is often single-threaded, meaning nonblocking i/o is necessary to achieve any concurrency.

Comment: Up to and including HTTP 1.1, clients must use your "blocking HTTP" example, unless they use a different connection for each request.  HTTP 2.0 allows for multiple requests to be in flight on the same connection, and responses do not have to be sent in the same order that the requests were sent in.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There's nothing in the world forcing you to wait idly for response, regardless of what protocol you use.

Answer (score 0):

> But what I understood from the concept and some of the sample implementations is that we implement code on the server side to achieve this nature of the code.

You implement code in whereever you are doing the non-blocking UI. What a server does has no bearing on whether a client uses blocking or non-blocking UI, and what a client does has no bearing on whether a server uses blocking or non-blocking UI.

> if (for example postman sending HTTP request to the server) the request has to wait for the server to respond, then what's the point of non-blocking I/O?

So that you're not wasting resources.

Let's consider first a simple console application that hits the web and then does something with the results. In this case there's very little to gain with non-blocking I/O as the application is just going to be sitting around waiting for something to do anyway.

Now let's consider a simple console application that hits 50 different web resources and collates the responses. Now non-blocking I/O is more useful, because with blocking I/O it would have to either get one resource after the other, or spin up 50 threads. With non-blocking I/O one, a small number of threads is all that is needed to hit 50 resources and respond promptly to each returning a response.

Now let's consider a GUI version of this application that wants to remain responsive to user input, while also running on low-power low-memory devices in which blocked threads are all the more expensive. The advantages of the above are increased.

Finally, consider a web application that is doing I/O both with the client and also as a client to a database, file system and maybe other web applications. It may have multiple requests at the same time, and blocking on either the I/O it does with the client or any of the I/O it does with db, file or other applications would cost a thread, which would put a scalability limit on how many requests it can handle simultaneously. Not blocking on I/O allows threads to be used for other requests while the I/O is pending.